# how to switch from embedded to python?

Tags: software-industry, career-development, applications, software-development, software

i have 5+ years of exp in embedded system in medium scale company. here i am working on only PIC controller. so now it became difficult for me to switch to other company. may i know the courses which will pick up my career. specially trending which are having scope.

Comment: As you have already coding experience, this might help you to get a quick overview: https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/python3/ Apart from that, I fully agree with the answer: training makes perfect.

Answer (score 4):

Do you do any Python scripting in your current job? If not, start doing so. There is always something that can be automated.

My current project has 16,500+ compiler warnings (!). On my first day, I spent 15 minutes to knock up a script to ignore the not so serious warnings (variable declared, but no used, etc), so that we could see the important ones. Until that, no one could see the wood for the trees, so no one address the serious warnings (possible loss of precision, alignment mismatch, variable read before being assigned, etc).

We use Finite State Machines, which are message driven. I coded a script to parse our log files and draw Message Sequence Charts, on the grounds that a picture speaks a thousand words. My colleagues love it.

I generate a lot of code using Python. On my last project, in one year I coded over 10k lines of Python and generated over 60k lines of C. On my current Ada project, within 6 weeks of joining I had committed more lines of code than the entire team had in the previous two years. Easy targets are anything tabular, such as min/max/default values, which can be generated from documentation.

In my case, I started by writing small scripts in my lunchtime, which helped the entire team. And gradually was given more Python coding to do as part of my job.

After a few years of that, I would not be afraid to interview for a pure Python job. So, start coding now, and approach you boss to ask if there is anything that you can automate, then take it from there.

> how to switch from embedded to python?

[Practice, practice, practice](https://www.nytimes.com/2009/11/29/nyregion/29fyi.html)